# ReactNative 0.55.4 FlatList — Tried to get frame for out of range index Infinity [iOS]

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I am rendering a Flatlist on a Modal, this seems to be important since the Flatlist is overflowing the modal, so my thesis is that the bugs are related.

The Flatlist is a Grid with many rows and columns, overflowing the modal it contains, after a couple of renders, it crashes (only in iOS) with the title description:

```
Tried to get frame for out of range index Infinity [iOS]
```

More over, this bug only happens during production or debugger is off, so can't reproduce it with the debugger making it so much harder to guess.

I tried all the related solutions, with no luck.